# How do I edge split after I duplicated a face?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, faces, edges, shortcut

I was creating a hand from a tutorial but when it came to the part where you needed to duplicate the face of the hand and edge split it by pressing space, it didn't work. keeps saying "error cannot split selected faces" Am I clicking the wrong key? or did I messed up my key binds?     YouTube tutorial TIME(5:04)(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-SNS_98FkM) [image]

Comment: Can you add your blend file to your question?  You're not clicking the wrong key.  The message mentions 'split' so it's trying to do what you want.  If you get that message when you try split with that screen shot, it's failing because it wants to split all four of the selected faces from something, but there's nothing to split them from.

Comment: or just make a small video with the last 3 steps you do before your error happens. but with full window please.

Comment: Try with ALT + M > Faces by Edges

Comment: tysm for helping me, the alt + m worked and i have completed making my hand